# Method bzip2 has died unexpectedly -Unable to update /upgrade /installl Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Unable to update/upgrade/install Ubuntu 14.04, and it shows the below:

```
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en [4,089 kB] 
E: Method bzip2 has died unexpectedly!
 E: Sub-process bzip2 received signal 25.
```

Also while upgrading - shows '0%':

I was fixing as error ' sts...0% ' while upgrading Ubuntu. I tried creating a manual `sources.list`. I reverted the changes to the file, but the error is still there.

Comment: #25 is SIGXFSZ -> the program wrote a file larger than permitted.  Usually no such limit is set; post the output of `ulimit -f`.

Comment: result of ulimit -f   is   15000

Answer (score 2):

> result of ulimit -f is 15000

This is the limit, in kB, on the size of files that can be written by the current shell or any descendent process.  It should normally be `unlimited`.  The install process will likely require writing files bigger than 15 MB.

> E: Sub-process bzip2 received signal 25.

Processes receive signals from other process or the OS kernel.  You can send them with `kill`; using ctrl-c, ctrl-d, etc. also sends signals.  You can see a list of them with `kill -l`:

```
 1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL       5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT      7) SIGBUS       8) SIGFPE       9) SIGKILL     10) SIGUSR1
11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGUSR2     13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM
16) SIGSTKFLT   17) SIGCHLD     18) SIGCONT     19) SIGSTOP     20) SIGTSTP
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGURG      24) SIGXCPU     25) SIGXFSZ
```

That's the first 25 on my system; they are mostly specified by POSIX (although only a handful with corresponding numbers).  In any case, this list is probably consistent across GNU/Linux.  If you search [this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) you'll see `SIGXFSZ` is supposed to mean "File size limit exceeded" and a bit more digging connects that to the `ulimit` settings.

`ulimit` can be use to set as well as get.  Try `sudo ulimit -f unlimited`, double check (`ulimit -f`) and then try your upgrade again.

Comment: ':~$ ulimit -f unlimited'
-bash: ulimit: file size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted   
   :~$ sudo ulimit -f unlimited
sudo: ulimit: command not found'

Comment: You have to have privileges to do the upgrade anyway, so just log in as root (or use `su`), check `ulimit -f` and change it if necessary, etc.  If you cannot do that, then you are stuck.  Without `root` access, you cannot change `ulimit -f` so you can't do anything that exceeds it.